# How to do a leftJoinAndSelect with subrelations (TypeORM)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeorm

I have four tables: SITE, SYSTEMS, TYPE, CATEGORY

SITE   ----hasMany---> SYSTEMS

SYSTEM ---belongsTo--> TYPE

TYPE   ---belongsTo--> CATEGORY

I want to get a site with all of its corresponding relations.

```
export const getLocalSiteByIdWithSystems = async (id) =>
  getManager().findOne(Site, null, {
    where: { id },
    relations: [
      'systems.type',
      'systems.type.category',
    ],
  });
```

But now, I need a query builder in order to make some custom sorts and validations. I tried this:

```
export const getLocalSiteByIdWithSystems = async (id) =>
  getManager()
    .createQueryBuilder(Site, 'site')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('site.systems', 'systems', 'systems.status = :status', {
      status: 'active',
    })
    .where('site.id = :id', { id })
    .orderBy('systems.created_at', 'DESC')
    .getOne();
```

So, my problem is that "systems" doesn't include "type". And I will need the relation "type" inside "systems" and "category" inside "type".

Any help will be very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply need to implement them:

```
 export const getLocalSiteByIdWithSystems = async (id) =>
  getManager()
    .createQueryBuilder(Site, 'site')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('site.systems', 'systems', 'systems.status = :status', {
      status: 'active',
    })
    .leftJoinAndSelect('systems.type', 'type') //
    .leftJoinAndSelect('type.category', 'category') //
    .where('site.id = :id', { id })
    .orderBy('systems.created_at', 'DESC')
    .getOne();
```